# Adding named turtles in list?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, append, turtle-graphics

I am currently working on a mini project where user enters a number and that number of turtles are generated and race to the middle. The turtles were created through `while` statement and then each named after its color using a nested `if` statement.

Is there any way to make a list of these turtles or a way to add them into a list which I can use random function on for the race to ensure a random color moves every turn. I can't seem to make a list containing the turtles names. (Below is simplified and focused version of my code.)

```
import turtle
y = turtle.turtle()
Racers = []
if Z == "Blue":
    Blue = y
    Racers.append(Blue)
elif Z == "Yellow":
    Yellow = y
    Racers.append(Blue)
etc.
```

Comment: You _could_ make a list of the turltes' names, in the same order as the turtles themselves. You just need `Names = []` at the top, then `Names.append('Blue')` inside the `if` (or, more simply, just get rid of the `if` and do `Names.append(z)`). But that's probably not what you want. Working with two completely independent lists is more complicated than working with a single list or other collection.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you want to use these names for, and where you want to access them, but I'll give you two different designs with different features.

First, instead of a list of turtle objects, you can keep a dict, mapping turtle names to turtle objects:

```
Racers = {}

y = turtle.turtle()
z = "Blue"
Racers[z] = y
```

Now, if you want a list of all the names, that's just a list of all the keys in `Racers`:

```
list(Racers)
```

Or, if you don't actually need a list, you just need to loop over them, just use `Racers` itself—when you loop over a dict, you get its keys.

If you want a list of the turtle objects, that's the values:

```
Racers.values()
```

If you want to loop over the names and objects together, that's the items:

```
for name, racer in Racers.items():
    print(name)
    racer.do_something()
```

The problem with this design is that you have a turtle, and you want to know his name, the only way to find out is to go through every `name, racer` in `items()` until you find the one that matches. If you never have to do that, this is a great design, but if you do, it's not.

---

Alternatively, you can stash the names as an extra attribute on the turtle objects themselves. You don't want to call the attribute `color`, because that hides a useful method on turtle objects, but you can call it, say, `name`:

```
Racers = []
y = turtle.turtle()
y.name = "Blue"
Racers.append(y)
```

Now you just have a list of turtles. And if you want to print out the winner's name, it's easier:

```
print('The winning turtle is', winning_turtle.name)
```

But if you want to look up a turtle by name, the only way to do it is to go through all the turtles and check their `name` until you find the right one.

---

So, both designs have tradeoffs. There are other possible designs (including combining the two ideas above, of course), all with their own tradeoffs. It's important to work out exactly how you're going to use your data before you pick a data structure. But, once you work that out, there's probably a way to do it, and if you can't figure it out yourself, you can ask a new question here.